# Ctrl+Shift+B doesn't work

Tags: bevel

Can anybody help me please ....
I am trying to bevel the vertice in the center (pic 01):
[image]

to achieve this (pic 02):
[image]

But whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> I got this (pic 03) instead:
[image]

... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work, I don't know why, but you can Ctrl B then V to switch to vertex bevel or back to edge bevel

Comment: @moonboots -- Just CTRL Z to try your tips -- CTRL B + V .. it works also .. thanks!!!

Comment: It might be that these edges aren't merged down into the face.  When you add an edge to an existing face don't use F, use J (i think!) instead, or select all and Face -> Weld Edges Into Faces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why: It has 2 segments. After change it into 1, I got exactly the bevel on my vertice in the center.